# How to debug a non working atmega88pa ciccuit. programmer can't connect

Tags: atmega, debugging

I am trying building a [Mutable Instruments Branches](https://github.com/pichenettes/eurorack/tree/master/branches/hardware_design/pcb) module which includes a atmega88pa.

I am trying to connect the programmer but can't get a connection going (I've tried the programmer with another board and it works there so I don't think the issue is with the programmer itself).

When I try to connect I get:

```
λ avrdude.exe -c usbasp -p m88p

avrdude.exe: error: program enable: target doesn't answer. 1
avrdude.exe: initialization failed, rc=-1
             Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
             this check.


avrdude.exe done.  Thank you.
```

The circuit for the MCU is
[image: Circuit]

the board is 0603 SMD component based. I used solderpaste and a skillet to reflow. Upon visual inspection everything looks okay. When I connect the power nothing heats up particularly.

How would I approach debugging this? I have a multimeter.

Would I measure the voltage at ping 29, 18, 4 and 6 to make sure they are at 5V?
How would I verify the MOSI/MISO and SCK connections being properly connected to the pins on the JTAG header?

Comment: **A difficult-to-troubleshoot possibility**: So-called "latch-up". When **AVCC** rises more slowly than **VCC**, internal latch-up occurs, which can cause all manner of strange behaviour. You might try shorting out L1 temporarily *while powering-up* to see if the processor magically comes to life. Shorting L1 should make AVCC rise right along with VCC.

Comment: Last time I work with factory new Atmels, they come with fuse sets to XTALL, so try some 12MHz one.

Answer (score 1):

Post a picture of your physical PCB, I might be able to help you. Everything looks good at the schematic but:

1. You are using avrdude to program it ,so I suppose you need it to have a bootloader), and connect the programmer (possibly a FTDI Basic) to RX/TX pins. How come you are using ISP for programming using avrdude?
2. Are your connections clean after soldering?
3. Maybe the MCU got burned while soldering.
4. If you are programming using atmel-ice, check the Miso/Mosi/SCK/Reset connections. Are they also clean after soldering?
5. Your MCU might be programmed to run using an external crystal connected. You done have any external crystals connected there.

I would also recommend you remove any external components not needed (like the LED, resistors etc) so that you are 100% sure they dont affect your MCU while programming, and connect them again later.